# Cheap times for tickets to Bora Bora

Tags: air-travel, tickets, air-france, french-polynesia

When is seasonally a good time to find cheap(er) tickets from Los Angeles to Bora Bora return?

Or is it always super expensive?

Comment: always super expensive :(

Answer (score 1):

You can sometimes find better deals during the winter months (Dec through Feb with the obvious exception of Christmas - New Years period), as that is rainy season for French Polynesia.  But these tend to be more hotel deals than airfare deals.  There are only a couple of airlines with limited flights from the USA to FP, so not much competition to produce lower fares.